# Regex: Getting a certain value from a URL

Tags: regex, jmeter

This is my url

```
http://localhost:8081/kma/accnt/user/201308000134/profile.html
```

using regex how can I retrieve this `201308000132`? how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how you are going to go about using regex to pull the number out, or what code is surrounding it, `\d+` will match to one or more numbers.

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for a reference page on basic regex syntax.

Edit: Because you have other numbers in there, I'd use either A) a look behind (as long as you aren't doing the regex in JavaScript, as it doesn't support look behinds) or B) by defining the minimum number of characters you want to make.

A) `\d+(?<=/\d+)` - match one or more numbers, look behind to check that there is a / preceding the numbers

B) `\d{5,}` - match any numbers, at least 5 of them, with no upper limit on how many it can match